# Unbiased estimator for $\tau(\theta) = \theta$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have  the next problem:

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ a sample of i.i.d random variables with probability function:

$$f(x;\theta)=2\theta ^2 x^{-3}$$

Find an unbiased estimator for $\tau(\theta)=\theta$

This is what I've done:

I found that the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ is $X_{(1)}$. I don't know how to use the invariance property so I can find the unbiased estimator, help.

Comment: That looks like a density, not a probability mass function (but terminology may vary). What's the interval for $x$?  Is $\theta > 0$ assumed?

Comment: $x \geq \theta$ and $\theta > 0$

Comment: Did you compute the mean for this distribution?

Comment: I don't know how :/

Comment: You don't know how to compute an expected value for a random variable, given its density function?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $$\Pr[X > x] = \frac{\theta^2}{x^2}, \quad x \ge \theta,$$

compute $$\Pr[X_{(1)} > x] = \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[X_i > x],$$ and from this, what can we say about the distribution of $X_{(1)}$?  Specifically, what is the bias $$\operatorname{E}[\hat \theta - \theta]$$ of $\hat \theta = X_{(1)}$ as a function of the sample size $n$ and $\theta$?  How could you modify $\hat \theta$ in a simple way to construct another estimator, $\tilde \theta = \tau(\hat \theta)$, such that $\operatorname{E}[\tilde \theta - \theta] = 0$?